# jQuery form Submit not working in JSF?

Tags: java, jquery, jquery-ui, jsf

I have a JSf form, I am tryin' to use jQuery Ui dialog plugin to submit the form.
here's the code snippet.

```
function confirmSubmit() {
          $('#dialog').dialog('open');
          return false;
      }

    $('#dialog').dialog({
        autoOpen : false,
        width : 400,
        modal : true,
        resizable : false,
        buttons : {
            "Submit Form" : function() {
                 document.myForm.submit();
            },
            "Cancel" : function() {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    });
<h:form id="myForm"> 
<h:commandLink action="#{Bean.search}" type="submit" onclick="return confirmSubmit()"   id="search" styleClass="buttonSearch">
                 </h:commandLink>
```

The "document.myForm.submit();" part in the dialog box isn't working i.e., no calls goes to the server and in the server console I see the error:

> 11:45:32,738 SEVERE [lifecycle]
>   JSF1054: (Phase ID: RENDER_RESPONSE 6,
>   View ID: /PRT01/IMCM0101.jsp)
>   Exception thrown during phase
>   execution:
>   javax.faces.event.PhaseEvent[source=com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl@ec333b]

The dialog box is appearing correctly but once i press the submit button "document.myForm.submit();" code is executed and the form is NOT submitted instead the above described error comes on the server console.

Comment: It's fixed now, some JSF parameters were missing. which jsf adds during form submissiom, I added them using jQuery 
    $("a[id$='search']").click(function() {
   
   var input = $("<input>").attr("type", "hidden").attr("name",   "myForm:search").val("myForm:search");
   $('#myForm').append($(input));
   $("p#dialog-email").html(titleVar);
    $('#dialog').dialog('open');
   
  });

Comment: What exception was thrown during phase execution? Please post its stacktrace. It contains the answer.

Comment: Hello BalusC, I have already posted the error that the server console was showing, I have also asnwered this question below, since in my form I have multiple command button each pointing to a different method of bean thus while doing "document.myForm.submit()", it wasn't taking the command button into consideration as i had done "onclick=return false;" as I wanted to submit the form using jQuery, thus i appended the required parameter "myform:search" using jQuery .append inside the form and now it works fine. It's something new which wasn't available on internet. Hope it helps other people.

Comment: You have not posted the exception. The error just tells `Exception thrown during phase execution:`. It is telling that **an** exception was been thrown. I was interested in which exception was been thrown. You should have read a bit back in the logs to find it.

Comment: I have just double checked but in the server log there is no exception trace just the above error, also on the UI the the complete page gets refreshed after i pressed the submit button on the jquery dialog box as required parameter "myForm:search" isn't passed in this request(saw the parameters using FireBug) until I deliberately add this "myForm:search" as hidden param using jquery only this the calls goes to the server(using eclipse debug mode  i am monitoring the calls to the server).

Comment: That is the ID of the link/button pressed. JSF needs to know it to understand which link/button was pressed so that the appropriate bean action can be invoked.

Comment: Yes, Exactly, I understood that after comparing parameters in firebug for 2 different calls, BTW you blog on communication in JSF is awesome, it really helped me learn JSF much faster! thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's done, some JSF parameters were missing. which jsf adds during form submissiom, I added them using jQuery:

```
$("a[id$='search']").click(function() {
    var input = $("<input>").attr("type", "hidden").attr("name",   "myForm:search").val("myForm:search");
    $('#myForm').append($(input));
    $("p#dialog-email").html(titleVar);
    $('#dialog').dialog('open');
});
```

Answer (score 3):

as you `return false;` it won't submit actually.

To make `dialog` working

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    var $dialog = $('<div></div>')
        .html('This dialog will show every time!')
        .dialog({
            autoOpen : false,
                            width : 400,
                            modal : true,
                            resizable : false,
                            buttons : {
                              "Submit Form" : function() {
                                       document.myForm.submit();
                               },
                               "Cancel" : function() {
                                       $(this).dialog("close");
                                }
                           }
                });


});
```

and then just call

```
 function confirmSubmit() {
      $dialog.dialog('open');
      return false;
  }
```

Comment: Hello Jigar, the dialog is working I have the code <div id="dialog" title="Verify Form jQuery UI Style">
   <p>
    <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert"
     style="float: left; margin: 0 7px 0 0;"></span>
   </p>Are you sure you want to 
   <p id="dialog-email"></p>
   <p>To edit, click Cancel.
   <p>
  </div>

Comment: The problem is not about the dialog but the the form submission in the jsf using "document.myForm.submit();"

Comment: just try `$("#myForm").submit();`

Comment: it's giving the same error on the server 3:20:06,255 SEVERE [lifecycle] JSF1054: (Phase ID: RENDER_RESPONSE 6, View ID: /PRT01/IMCM0101.jsp) Exception thrown during phase execution: javax.faces.event.PhaseEvent[source=com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl@162ad2c]